# How to store and send the files of a queue when internet is available

Tags: android, android-internet

We are beginning with Android. We want to programmatically send files when internet is available (by email). We guess the best way to program it is to send the files to a queue if there isn't internet. When internet is detected, the files will begin to be uploaded one by one. We guess the code should be like the following:

A background service continually checks if there is internet:

```
public class EducarCabezoService extends Service{
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();                 
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);        
        ciReceiver = new checkInternetReceiver();
        registerReceiver(ciReceiver, filter);
```

The background service uses a BroadcastReceiver for that purpose:

```
public class checkInternetReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {     
        Intent uqofIntent = new Intent(context, UploadQueueOfFilesService.class);
        context.startService(uqofIntent);
```

We didn't find **how to put files in a queue** (maybe it is not the normal procedure). We can use the method isOnline() from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-timeouts):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public uploadFile (){
        if (!isOnline()){
            // TODO Send files to queue?
```

We neither know **how to upload those files from that queue**:

```
public class UploadQueueOfFilesService extends Service{
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Start uploading files
```

Comment: This sounds like a good use case for [Square's Tape](http://square.github.io/tape/).

Comment: Save the files to storage. An "out" folder for example. If there's files in there, upload. Here's an option for internal and external storage: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: You should be monitoring [CONNECTIVITY_ACTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION) instead of SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION. See [this article](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html#MonitorChanges) about monitoring connectivity status.

Answer (score -1):

This will save a file (to "internal storage", you can also use external storage (if their device has it)):

```
String FILENAME = "out/file1";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

When you go online, just look for files in the out directory. Upload and delete them one by one.

**EDIT:** Alternatively, if the files are already in storage, and you don't want to copy or delete them, use a SQLite table to store a row for every file your service should upload, and then delete the row from the table.